# Finding the position function of time $r(t) = (x,y)$ given the acceleration function $a(x,y) = (a_{x}, a_{y})$

Tags: kinematics, orbital-motion

Let me preface this question by saying that I've only taken mathematics through Calculus II and the first general physics class offered at my university, so the methods necessary to solve this problem might be out of my depth, but I will try my best to understand.

I finished all my studying for finals early, and was playing around with this problem:

*Consider perfectly spherical planet of mass $M_{p}$ and a projectile object of mass $M_{o}$. The object is fired from the surface of the planet with speed $v_{0}$ at an angle $\theta$ from the horizontal. For a given value of $\theta$, find $v_{0}$ such that the object's trajectory path will bring the object into perfectly spherical orbit around the planet. Ignore air resistance. Assume that the gravitational acceleration **does** vary with height as $g = -\frac{GM_{p}}{r^{2}}$.*

**Here's everything I have:** The object is fired with an initial speed $v_{0}$ and thus (assuming $U_{g} = 0$ at the surface of the planet) will have a total energy of $K_{0} = \frac{1}{2}M_{o}v_{0}^{2}$.

If we say that the object reaches orbit at height $h$, then the work done by gravity, where $R$ is the planet's radius, and $r$ is the distance from the object to the planet's surface is
$$
W_{g} = GM_{p}M_{o}\int_{R}^{R+h}\frac{dr}{r^2} = \frac{GM_{p}M_{o}}{R + h} - \frac{GM_{p}M_{o}}{R}.
$$
To be in orbit at height $h$, the object must be traveling with a tangential velocity $v_{tan} = \sqrt{\frac{GM_{p}}{h}}$, and will therefore have the kinetic energy $K_{tan} = \frac{1}{2}M_{o}v_{tan}^{2} = \frac{GM_{p}M_{o}}{2h}$. Then at the exact point where the object enters the orbital path, gravity must have done the work $W_{g} = K_{0} - K_{tan} = \frac{1}{2}M_{o}v_{0}^{2} - \frac{GM_{p}M_{o}}{2h}$. I'm not sure if this will be helpful, but I'll include it anyways.

Now here is where I am getting stuck: the gravitational acceleration at some point $\vec{P} = <P_{x},P_{y}>$ will be a function of the magnitude of $\vec{P}$. Essentially, I have an acceleration function $\vec{a}(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are the components of a position vector, and I need to find $\vec{r}(t)$, $\vec{v}(t)$, etc...

I've googled / searched all over this and the Mathematics SE, and I haven't found much. I did come across a few solutions to one dimensional cases where you have an acceleration function of position $a(x)$ and you need to solve for a position function of time $x(t)$, but nothing for a two dimensional case.

Please let me know if any part of the problem doesn't make sense. I've tried my best to frame it, but I understand that my limited knowledge of technical physics and mathematics may affect my ability to properly frame the problem.

Comment: You might be overthinking this. For the orbit to be in perfect spherical orbit around the planet the gravitational force has to be equal to the centripetal force i.e $ m a_c = m g(r)$  where $ a_c$ is centripetal acceleration and $g(r)$ is gravitational acceleration as a function of height. So all one needs to do is to solve this equation. This is essentially a question about geocentric orbits, you can look up how that is usually solved and make the necessary changes related to gravitational constant varying with height.

Comment: Yes, but I'm firing the object from the surface of the planet at an angle, and gravity will exert an acceleration upon the object as it flies as a function of height just as it will do so once it reaches orbital height. Doesn't that make the problem much more complicated? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: The only complication I can see is that you should care about only the tangential component of the velocity since that is what goes into centripetal acceleration. That is where the angle comes in but apart from that, this should be a standard geocentric orbit calculation.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it. That being said, I'm full aware of my relative lack of knowledge of the subject, so perhaps I'm just not there yet.

Comment: What is a spherical orbit?  Is the the same as a circular orbit?  If so, then step back and think before writing down equations.  You might find a short-cut to the answer.  Another hint:  you say "at the exact point where the object enters the orbital path."  Think about that point and what has to happen there.  (If a spherical orbit is different from a circular orbit, then ignore what I've said, and be sure to define what a spherical orbit is in your question.)

Comment: @garyp I'm sorry, yes I meant circular orbit. Ok...so I know that the initial vertical component of the velocity needs to be just enough to make it to 'orbital height'... Does this mean that the horizontal component merely needs to be the same magnitude as the tangential velocity required to stay in orbit at orbital height? That feels too easy, but both you and Amara have hinted that I'm vastly over-complicating things, which is something I tend to do a lot in physics, if I don't have an immediately strong grasp of how to solve the problem.

Comment: @CookieToast, What does it take for an object to remain in circular orbit at some radius around another object? Answer, the gravitational force of the bigger object has to be strong enough to create the right amount of centripetal force. Now how much centripetal force do I need at some radius, r ? This depends on mass  and angular velocity of object. For the moment first concentrate on calculating the centripetal acceleration assuming the orbit is at some height $h_0$ or radius $r$. What is the formula for $a_c$?

Comment: It is not possible to get into a circular orbit without an additional change in velocity if $\theta\neq0$.

Comment: Here's another obscure hint.  We model the boost phase as an impulsive boost.  I.e. it happens all at once.  The rocket is at rest, and the next instant it's at full speed, and there are no other impulses.   The instant after the boost, the rocket is in its orbit.  (I like this problem.)